# How does the concept of a class change when passing data to the constructor instead of method parameters?

Tags: oop, interface, parameters, constructor

Let's say we're making a parser. One implementation could be:

```
public sealed class Parser1
{
    public string Parse(string text)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Or we could pass the text to the constructor instead:

```
public sealed class Parser2
{
    public Parser2(string text)
    {
       this.text = text;
    }

    public string Parse()
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Usage is simple in both cases, but what does it *mean* to enable parameter input to `Parser1`, compared to the other? What message have I sent to a fellow programmer, when they look at the API? Also, are there any technical advantages/disadvantages in certain cases?

Another question comes up when I realize that an interface would be quite meaningless in the second implementation:

```
public interface IParser
{
    string Parse();
}
```

...where an interface on the first one could serve at least some purpose. Does that signify anything in particular, that a class is "interfaceable" or not?

Comment: This probably belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Seems you have an inaccurate understanding of these concepts: class, interface, constructor, message-passing etc. For example, message passing, in OOP, refers to calling a method on an object. It does not mean sending messages among the developer.

Comment: Please @NazarMerza, I meant from a higher information standpoint than object message passing. Glancing at class documentation for example, can give hints ("send a message") how to use it.

Comment: @JAB, you're right, forgot about that forum. I will repost there.

Answer (score 2):

> Usage is simple in both cases, but what does it mean to enable parameter input to Parser1, compared to the other?

If you specify a parameter in the constructor, you're implying that the parameter will be used throughout the class.  If you specify a parameter in a setter method, you're implying that the value of the parameter might not be known at the time you create an instance of the class.

Here's a real world example of needing a setter method.

```
public class A {
    private B b;
}

public class B {
    private A a;
}
```

Assume classes A and B have all the appropriate getters and setters.  The constructor is the empty constructor for both classes.

In order to initialize both classes, you'd have to write code that looks like this.

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
a.setB(b);
b.setA(a);
```

> Does that signify anything in particular, that a class is "interfaceable" or not?

Generally, you write an interface when there can be more than one concrete class that satisfies the requirements of the interface.

As an example, in Java, the `List` interface is implemented by `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`.

The other reason for writing an interface is that you want to establish the required methods that a concrete class has to implement, even if only one concrete class will ever be written.

Sometimes, an abstract class is a better way to define a base class.  It depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

In general an interface is a good idea, even if you only have one implementation. It makes your code more flexible, especially because you could then adopt the **dependency injection** principle: inject concrete instances in the **constructor** of your classes. It makes your code also extremely testable and users of your class know what to expect, and also know what dependencies there are. Doing so allows you to inject your parser into other classes, like:

```
public class Worker
{
    private IParser _parser;
    public Worker(IParser parser)
    {
        _parser=parser;
    }
}
```

Programming against interfaces also decouples your code from the actual implementation. As an example: classes in your domain layer use repository interfaces; but know nothing about the concrete repository implementations, because they are injected at runtime. Therefore the domain is independent of infrastructural concerns.

Concerning the `text` parameter: in your case it would probably be better a parameter of the `Parse` operation, because it will not be used outside that operation and you could call the `Parse` method multiple times with different strings. If you do this in the constructor, it means that you will probably have multiple operations that will work with it and so it is more like a global variable to the operation.